# Perform Load Test for RoR 2.1 Web Application & Server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, web-applications, load-testing

I have a web application on `RoR 2.1` and backend `MySQL` up and running with around 8k users and now i want to do a `Load Test` on my web app and server to figure out the `load on the server and the average and peak number of concurrent users.`

What are the ways of implementing this load test to analyse the load on the server and performance of the web application with a way to figure out average and peak number of concurrent users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using ab (apache benchmarks http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html) for load tests. Example of testing on google.com:

```
ab -n 10000 -c 100 http://google.com/
```

It allows me to investigate how much requests per second my setup(application) can do as well as concurrency level.

The ab tool is a part of the Apache httpd package in CentOS and Red Hat distributions. So it is probably already installed there. For Ubuntu/Debian install apache2-utils package.

```
ab --help for full options list
```

The most important are :

```
-n requests     Number of requests to perform
-c concurrency  Number of multiple requests to make
```

Also i'm monitoring peaks of activity with munin(http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html) and plugins for nginx/passenger/unicorn/CPU/Memory depending on configuration, as well as plugin for MySQL which shows total amount of queries per second and many more data.

You can install munin using appropriate tutorial for your RH linux from that page http://munin-monitoring.org/wiki/LinuxInstallation.

Here also quite nice article about munin and mongrel monitoring:
http://onrails.org/2007/08/31/monitoring-rails-performance-with-munin-and-a-mongrel

You could pick up plugins for apache(and not only) monitoring from the http://exchange.munin-monitoring.org.

Good thing about that all that it doesnt require to change application. So you can just install it and use without any changes from your production setup.

Comment: Thanks could you be able to provide me with doc on the installation and usage steps. And also how will i be able to fetch the details pertaining to the figure on 'average and peak number of concurrent users'?

Comment: Also the server of my app isnt apache its Mongrel

Comment: What OS do you have on server?

Comment: Red Hat Linux is the Server OS

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I shall look into it.